# Change header color per page to, one different color per page

Tags: css, wordpress, colors, header

I want to change the color of my header while maintaining the color of the main page.

On my main page the letters are black and when I go to the other pages I want the letters to be white, my site is made in WordPress and with this code I change the color of my header`your text`

```
#header .header_default, #header .header_default .stm_header_links a, #header .header_default .header_main_menu_wrapper a, #header .header_default .header_top_bar a, #header .header_default .right_buttons a > i, #header .header_default .header_top_bar {
    color: #EDEDED ;
}
```

I managed to change the color of the header but I need it to be white on the main page and on the other pages the letters be black

Answer (score 0):

WordPress automatically adds `home` class to the body element of the front page of the site.

So you can target the front page using these styles

```
body.home #header .header_default, body.home #header .header_default .stm_header_links a, body.home #header .header_default .header_main_menu_wrapper a, body.home #header .header_default .header_top_bar a, body.home #header .header_default .right_buttons a > i, body.home #header .header_default .header_top_bar {
    color: white;
}
```

For the pages that are not homepage, you can use this:

```
body:not(.home) #header .header_default, body:not(.home) #header .header_default .stm_header_links a, body:not(.home) #header .header_default .header_main_menu_wrapper a, body:not(.home) #header .header_default .header_top_bar a, body:not(.home) #header .header_default .right_buttons a > i, body:not(.home) #header .header_default .header_top_bar {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend. When i have 15 reputation i like u.